# There is a class matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot, but the module matplotlib.axes has no attribute AxesSubplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
print type(ax)
```

gives the output

```
<class 'matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot'>
```

Then the code

```
import matplotlib.axes
matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot
```

raises the exception

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AxesSubplot'
```

To summarize, there is a class `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot`, but the module `matplotlib.axes` has no attribute `AxesSubplot`. What on earth is going on?

I'm using Matplotlib 1.1.0 and Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Is there an actual problem you're trying to solve with this, or is this question just curiosity?

Comment: @Julian: It is "just curiosity". I believe that curiosity makes you a better developer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Heh.  That's because there *is* no `AxesSubplot` class.. until one is needed, when one is built from `SubplotBase`.  This is done by some magic in `axes.py`:

```
def subplot_class_factory(axes_class=None):
    # This makes a new class that inherits from SubplotBase and the
    # given axes_class (which is assumed to be a subclass of Axes).
    # This is perhaps a little bit roundabout to make a new class on
    # the fly like this, but it means that a new Subplot class does
    # not have to be created for every type of Axes.
    if axes_class is None:
        axes_class = Axes

    new_class = _subplot_classes.get(axes_class)
    if new_class is None:
        new_class = new.classobj("%sSubplot" % (axes_class.__name__),
                                 (SubplotBase, axes_class),
                                 {'_axes_class': axes_class})
        _subplot_classes[axes_class] = new_class

    return new_class
```

So it's made on the fly, but it's a subclass of `SubplotBase`:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
>>> print type(ax)
<class 'matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot'>
>>> b = type(ax)
>>> import matplotlib.axes
>>> issubclass(b, matplotlib.axes.SubplotBase)
True
```

Comment: Shouldn't the class be created then when I run the first code snippet, and be present as an attribute of matplotlib.axes when I run the second code snippet?

Comment: It *is* created, but it's not stored at module level.  Look in `matplotlib.axes._subplot_classes`: you should see `{matplotlib.axes.Axes: matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot}`.  Note that in the factory function the `new_class` gets added to the `_subplot_classes` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see what DSM said:

```
In [1]: from matplotlib import pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                                                       

In [2]: type(plt.gca()).__mro__                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[2]: 
(matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot,
 matplotlib.axes._subplots.SubplotBase,
 matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes,
 matplotlib.axes._base._AxesBase,
 matplotlib.artist.Artist,
 object)
```

with the dunder [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) you can find all the inheritances of some class.