# AxisSubplot , convert display coordinates into real coordinates

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to use a `AxisSubplot` object to convert some display coordinates to real coordinates for drawing shapes onto the plot. The problem is I can't find documentation or `AxisSubplot` *anywhere* , I see [Axis](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html) but can't figure out what on earth is contained in an `AxisSubplot` object.

My plot coordinates are displayed by Time x Altitude, so **display** wise a set may be

```
[ ['03:42:01', 2.3] , ['03:42:06', 3.4] , ...]
```

In my display function I format the axis of the subplot like so:

```
    fig.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(mpl.dates.AutoDateLocator())
    fig.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Now when I want to display a polygon using for example the set above, how can I convert that date string to plot cooridnates?

```
    points = [['03:42:01', 1], ['03:43:01', 2.1], ['03:21:01', 1]]
    polygon = plt.Polygon(points)
    fig.add_patch(polygon)
```

And of course this gives me the error `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 03:42:01`. Would anyone know how to do this? Here's an example of what the plot axis looks like:

[image]

Comment: This is at least two questions. I suggest making a minimal runnable example with, say, a 10x10 array of random sample data. For the polygon, you're dealing with the `transform` from dates to floats -- matplotlib has a standard isomorphism that we usually don't think about, but looks like you will. So make the example and check out the [transformations tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html?highlight=transformations), which covers axis/figure/data differences too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have two issues:

1. You can't find the documentation of the `AxesSubplot` object.

   That is because it is only created at runtime. It inherits from [`SubplotBase`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py#L16). You'll find more details in [this answer (to the same question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690800/4177384).
2. You would like to plot a polygon with dates/times as x coordinates:

   For that matplotlib needs to know that your coordinates represent dates/times. There are some plotting functions which can handle datetime objects (e.g. `plot_date`), but in general you have to take care of that.

   Matplotlib uses its own internal representation of dates (floating number of days), but provides the necessary conversion functions in the `matplotlib.dates` module. In your case you could use it as follows:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.dates as mdates
   from datetime import datetime

   # your original data
   p = [['03:42:01', 1], ['03:43:01', 2.1], ['03:21:01', 1]]

   # convert the points 
   p_converted = np.array([[mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S')), y] 
           for x,y in p])

   # create a figure and an axis
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

   # build the polygon and add it
   polygon = plt.Polygon(p_converted)
   ax.add_patch(polygon)

   # set proper axis limits (with 5 minutes margins in x, 0.5 in y)
   x_mrgn = 5/60./24.
   y_mrgn = 0.5
   ax.set_xlim(p_converted[:,0].min() - x_mrgn, p_converted[:,0].max() + x_mrgn)
   ax.set_ylim(p_converted[:,1].min() - y_mrgn, p_converted[:,1].max() + y_mrgn)

   # assign date locators and formatters 
   ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
   ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

   # show the figure
   plt.show()
   ```

   Result:

   [image]

Comment: @SyntacticFructose does that solve your problem / answer your question?