# Calling a different bound method of any instance based on an external condition

Tags: python-3.x, methods

This is a generic problem but I'd like to ask the question based on a concrete example. But please keep in mind the generality (not necessarily static or class methods).

Suppose I'd like to draw regular plots or loglog plots depending on a conditional `draw_log` with the some data. We set up the figure and the axes

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y = [1,2,3], [10, 200, 1]
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(3, 2)
draw_log = False

for row in range(3):
    for col in range(2):
        # The loop to be removed
        if draw_log:
            ax_lst[row, col].plot(x, y)
        else:
            ax_lst[row, col].loglog(x, y)
```

What I would like to use is the first class citizenship of the methods such that

```
plotter = ?????.plot if draw_log else ?????.loglog
```

and then use the generic `plotter` method name `ax_lst[row, col].plotter(x, y)` but this requires to access the method on the particular instance not the parent class.

I've searched for *passing the method name as a parameter* type questions but they seem to be related either to the assignment within the class definition or external methods.

How can I point the assignment to the method belonging to any instance?

Comment: So, basically you want to replace the whole if-else statement in your example with one function call, right?

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov For this particular problem yes that would be the goal. But for a more general problem suppose you want to control the behavior of many method calls with an if-switch placed at the top. Ideally I would like to control the method name called from an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `plotter` method.

Your `ax_lst[row, col]` are instances of `<class 'matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot'>`, but there's no such class in `matplotlib.axes`. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690800/550094),

> there is no AxesSubplot class.. until one is needed, when one is built
>   from SubplotBase

So we can add it to SubplotBase:

```
import matplotlib.axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = [1,2,3], [10, 200, 1]
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(3, 2)
draw_log = False

def plotter(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return getattr(self, 'plot' if draw_log else 'loglog')(*args, **kwargs)

matplotlib.axes.SubplotBase.plotter = plotter

for row in range(3):
    for col in range(2):
        ax_lst[row, col].plotter(x, y, 'r-')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I read your question again, and, well, my first answer wasn't what you asked... This should be it!

Comment: Indeed I guess there is no other way to do in-place replacement of the method name. So I would use something similar for it. Thanks!